# How can I apply global styles to styled-components in Storybook?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components, storybook

I've created a theme and I'm trying to apply it to all of my components and render it in Storybook. I looked at the API [here](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#createglobalstyle) and [here](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/writing-stories/decorators) I can see I'm missing something because when I load the app I get the error `ReferenceError: React is not defined`

My return statement is causing the error because when I comment it out I no longer get the error. What am I doing wrong?

```
// preview.js

import { getGlobalStyleSheet } from '../src/styles/globalStyle';
import { addDecorator, addParameters } from '@storybook/react';
import { createGlobalStyle } from 'styled-components';


addDecorator(story => {
  const styleSheet = getGlobalStyleSheet('light');
  const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle` ${styleSheet}`;

  return (
    <>
      <GlobalStyle />
      {story()}
    </>
  );
});
```

Comment: You need to import React (`import React from 'react';`) in order to return JSX

Comment: Wow, the example codebase I was using is missing that yet, somehow it works. Thanks.